# DataTable rows doesn't update after deleting a row from SQLite flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am new to flutter and I made a SQLite database with data and I show the data in a Datatable. Whenever I select a row from the Datatable, a float action button appear to delete the row. After deleting the row, the Datatable doesn't update unless you leave the screen and comeback again.

The Datarow data is stored in a list from my SQLite class and I get it after reading all data from the Database.

Please help me!! I have been struggling with this problem for 4 days.

Is there a way to refresh the Datatable data or refresh the screen to update the Datatable?

Datatable Widget code:

```
  Widget builddatatable() {
    final coulmns = [
      '${sultandbfield.Customer_Name}',
      '${sultandbfield.Customer_Number}',
    ];
    return DataTable(
      columns: getColumns(coulmns),
      rows: getRows_2(notes),
    );
  }


  Future<List<SultanDB>> generate_data() async {
    var decode_data =
        json.decode("$full_json_data").cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    List<SultanDB> data_list =
        await decode_data.Map<SultanDB>((json) => SultanDB.fromJson(json))
            .toList();
    return data_list;
  }

  List<DataRow> getRows_2(List<SultanDB> sultandb) =>
      sultandb.map((SultanDB sultandb) {
        final cells = [sultandb.Customer_Name, sultandb.Customer_Number];
        return DataRow(
            selected: selected_data.contains(sultandb),
            onLongPress: () {
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "${sultandb.Customer_ID}");
            },
            onSelectChanged: (isSelected) => setState(() {
                  final isAdding = isSelected != null && isSelected;
                  isAdding
                      ? {
                          selected_data.add(sultandb),
                          Float_appear(),
                        }
                      : {
                          selected_data.remove(sultandb),
                          Float_appear(),
                        };
                }),
            cells: getCells(cells));
      }).toList();

  List<DataCell> getCells(List<dynamic> cells) => cells
      .map((data) => DataCell(
            Text('${data}'),
          ),)
      .toList();

  List<DataColumn> getColumns(List<String> coulmns) => coulmns
      .map((String column) => DataColumn(
            label: Text(column),
          ))
      .toList();
```

and read all data to a list is
`notes<SultanDB> = await sultandata.instance.readalldata();`

and delete customer onpress action:

```
List<int> user_ids = [];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < selected_data.length ; i++) {
          user_ids.add(int.parse(selected_data[i].Customer_ID.toString()));
        }
        
        Delete_customer(user_ids);
```

Comment: please add you code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read data from SQLite after delete or just delete the specific data that you just remove from list that you hold the all data and then run setstate.

you can do this after delete data:

```
Delete_customer(user_ids);
var result = await sultandata.instance.readalldata();
setState(() {
   notes = result;
});
```

Comment: I cant setstate the list because I need to await the data from the database i tried to do async for setstate but i get error

Comment: if you add more code, I can help you better

Comment: I edited the question and added the codes I hope you can help

Comment: I did not understand why you can not call set state after Delete_customer(user_ids) ?

Comment: if i try to setstate: 
setState(() async {
          notes = await sultandata.instance.readalldata();
        }); 
then i get this error:
E/flutter (23398): The setState() method on _screen_customers_listState#43934 was called with a closure or method that returned a Future. Maybe it is marked as "async".
E/flutter (23398): Instead of performing asynchronous work inside a call to setState(), first execute the work (without updating the widget state), and then synchronously update the state inside a call to setState().

Comment: that is not the correct way. see my update

Comment: do you have telegram or discord so I can dm you?